# Ember component inserting two table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js

I'm trying to create a component that manages two table  row:
- one holding all the table row data.
- another one holding for displaying error message in input.

component html:

component template

```
<td>{{input value=one}}</td>
<td>{{two}}</td>
<td>{{three}}</td>

{{#if error}}
<tr>
  <td colspan=3>{{errorMessage}}</td>
</tr>
{{/if}}
```

component js:

```
App.EntryComponent = Ember.Component.extend ({
  layoutName : 'components/entry.hbs',
  tagName : "tr"
});
```

This is obviously wrong, as one tr is nested within the wrapper tr (the component tagName is tr).
However I'm not sure how to have a component manager two tr? Is that even possible?

Would love to hear back any suggestions.
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after spending almost a full day I believe I've discovered how to handle this.
I'm posting this answer, as this might help other people that might struggle with the same problem.

Seems that with Ember 1.8.x is it possible by making providing an empty tagName.

So you change the template to :

```
<tr>
  <td>{{input value=one}}</td>
  <td>{{two}}</td>
  <td>{{three}}</td>
</tr>

{{#if error}}
<tr>
  <td colspan=3>{{errorMessage}}</td>
</tr>
{{/if}}
```

And the component controller to:

```
App.EntryComponent = Ember.Component.extend ({
  layoutName : 'components/entry.hbs',
  tagName : ""
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with tagName being a `table`? Have you considered that?

Comment: @KalmanHazins that won't really cut it, as there are multiple entries in the table and I want each component handling one entry..

Comment: OK, so then is it fair to say that each row/component in your table contains 1 or 2 rows, in which case you can make tagName a row(tr)? Just thinking out loud...

Comment: Interesting, I wonder if a blank tagName is supported? In my case I do things like this by making it `tbody` and having one or more `tr`'s within.

Comment: @aceofspades ya but then again, you're creating an outside component just like wrapping it with table (which is exactly like a table but without the thead..), I want a component that lists two tr, think about it, why not? I'm not sure if it's supported but with 1.8.x it working, I had 1.5.x before and I could just add another <tr></tr> inside the template and it would close the previous <tr>